# find xsd/schema types subset being *used* in an xml instance/document (skip unused xsd types)

Tags: xml, xsd

Given

- an xml document / xml instance
- the xsd schema

is there a tool that can determine the subset of xsd types (of the schema) that were actually USED in that specific xml instance?

(I would like to skip all the xsd types present in the schema BUT NOT USED in the xml)

e.g. my xsd might define 1000 xsd types, but in my xml I only used 20 of those types. I want to extract only those 20 types being used.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Saxon schema validator has an option `-stats:filename` designed to provide this information. See https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!schema-processing/commandline

(To be honest, I haven't used it in a while: please let us know how you get on with it).

You'll need an evaluation license for Saxon-EE, obtainable from https://www.saxonica.com/download/download.xml

Comment: At first I thought OP's request and this feature might be used in a sort of dead code removal (compilers) or tree shaking (JavaScript builds), but as I thought though it a bit more, neither seem to be viable: The usefulness of dead component removal or an XSD shaking feature that considered components reached in the course of assessing a single document instance would be bound by the representativeness of the instance.  I'm left wondering what OP's need for this information might actually be.

Comment: The stats file can be accumulated over a large set of instances, and that might give you a good indication of the subset of the vocabulary used in a given corpus, which might guide you in knowing, for example, where your tests need to be extended.

Comment: Sometimes, people chose to use an existing xsd type which has tons of dependencies, only because they need one simple element and none of those  dependencies. I am aware of the fact that my approach, in theory, is far from being one that allows me to deal with *any* xml instance "based" on that schema. Except that, it might be far more practical. Think about mapping one xsd type instead of 1000. And this is a real example, and 1:1000 is the real scale of the practical vs theoretical use of my schemas. Well, life is .... complicated. Thanks for the feedback!!